# IJCAD　文字スタイルにて「ＭＳ Ｐゴシック」を設定する方法

Tags: .net, ijcad

IJCADの文字スタイルにて「ＭＳゴシック」は、以下のコードで設定できるのですが、
「ＭＳ **Ｐ**ゴシック」はどのようにすれば設定できるのでしょうか？

```
Dim txtStyleTblRec As TextStyleTableRecord = New TextStyleTableRecord()

With txtStyleTblRec
    .Name = styleName
    .FileName = "C:\Windows\Fonts\msgothic.ttc"
    .TextSize = 0
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

文字スタイルにTrueTypeフォントを設定する場合は、FileName プロパティを使用するのではなく、Fontプロパティを使用してフォントを割り当てるようにしてください。

AutoCADのヘルプですが次の記事が参考になると思います。
[フォントを割り当てる(.NET)](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2016/JPN/?guid=GUID-F3013EB5-214C-415A-B1B9-439C325049FF)

```
Dim font = New FontDescriptor("ＭＳ Ｐゴシック", False, False, 128, 50)
```

このような感じで、FontDescriptorオブジェクトを作成して、Fontプロパティに割り当てることで、文字スタイルに「ＭＳ Ｐゴシック」を設定できると思います。